# z-index child div in different grouping that have absolute position

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this problem

This is the HTML

```
 <div class="view">
   <div class=" slice b1"  ">
     <div class="slice b2"  ">
       <div class="slice b3" ">
         <div class="slice b4"  ;">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class=" slice f1" >
     <div class="slice f2 " >
       <div class="slice f3 " >
         <div class="slice f4 " >
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see a have 2 groups hierarchical chained the b1 > b2> b3> b4 
and f1 >f2 > f3 > f4

Can i control the z-index so that f1 f2 f3 and f4 are at first on top and after let say hover or active b1 and b4 will cover f1 f2 f3 and f4( by rotation and translation and z-index)

I am concerned only about the z-index property the rest i already solved.

The problem i am trying to resolve is paper folding simulation and here is the entire code 
http://codebeautify.org/alleditor/a66bcd

Comment: You want to animate something? I would definitely suggest using a canvas then.

Comment: i have already done it using combination of canvas html 5 and css 3 you can see it in the link above the problem is that i can't replicate exactly what i what and the problem seams to be with the Z-index property

Comment: Well, z-index is a CSS property. You should be able to modify it on hover or whenever you want, just defining the function. It could be that some browsers don't refresh it at all. Maybe you'll have to refresh the DOM

Comment: Also, it could be that the onhover function works for both chains of divs, so it is executed twice and thus causing the error

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: no.

The long answer: not the way you have your nesting set up.

You have to understand that every element gains its own stacking context based on its *n*-level from document root and hierarchy.  So your `f` and `b` stacks are siblings and share a stacking context.  `F` can overlap `B` by way of z-index, but `F1` cannot overlap `B1` by way of stacking context.

Consider this example:

```
-F0
--F1
---F2a
---F2b
----F3
-B0
--B1a
---B2
--B1b
```

The stacking contexts are as follow:

1. **R0** - F0 & B0
2. **F1** - F1
3. **F2** - F2a & F2b
4. **F3** - F3
5. **B1** - B1a & B1b
6. **B2** - B2

These stacking contexts don't interact with one another unless they are siblings.  If I change **B** stack to `z-index: 2` and **F1** stack to `z-index: 999999999`, the **B** stack will still always be over the **F1** stack, since all that ridiculously high z-index is saying is that **F1** is 999,999,999 levels above its siblings (which it has none).  Accordingly, all of the **B** stack will display over all of the **F** stack, because the **B** stack now has a higher `z-index` on an element closer to document root.

So in order to get the behavior you want, you'll have to pseudo stack using a combination of `position: absolute` and `z-index`.

Keep in mind, you'll need some kind of positioning regardless, since the default `position: static` doesn't allow for stack floating by way of `z-index`.